# ionic cordova run android failed with exit code 1 in ionic 3

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm making a simple camera preview project in ionic 3. I first added the platform with the command:

> $ ionic cordova platform add android

Then when I try to run the project with:

> $ ionic cordova run android

I get this message
[image]

I tried removing the android platform and then again adding it but it doesn't work.

Comment: have you tried deleting from the device the app installed with the same bundle?

Comment: Yes that was the problem. Thank you very much.

Comment: next time add the relevant error in the question, what you asked above didn't say a lot about your problem!

Answer (score 0):

You have installed app with same package name, uninstall it and try again